# Labeling layer features in Avenza Maps

Tags: symbology, pdf, geospatial-pdf, avenza

I have a geospatial PDF map: https://github.com/natearoe/myrepo/blob/master/CopperVeg.pdf

I have a .kmz with plot locations: https://github.com/natearoe/myrepo/blob/master/VegPlotsKML.kmz

Both can be easily added into Avenza maps and the layer (.kmz file) can be linked to the map allowing you to see plot locations on the map. Currently, they only appear as tiny white dots. I want the names of the features to be displayed on the map, such as '2016AK261101.'

Is this possible, perhaps using the Pro version?

Comment: would you be open to other software solutions?

Comment: Yes. Preferably compatible with iOS and Android.

Comment: Shapefiles in the Pro version will not help you. I tried a quick test and a point layer is shown as a red pin. I expect you can change the symbol (I didn't try too hard to do that), but that still won't display any text. Unless you really want the plot locations as a separate layer, you're better off styling the map to exactly what you want and then exporting, as suggested in the answer by @Mapperz

Answer (score 2):

If the titles of each of the features are labeled as you want, you can tap on those dots and see the callout/name displayed.  There's currently no way to have the labels display automatically, but it is being worked on!

Answer (score 1):

Loading in the two data sources:

- CopperVeg.pdf
- VegPlotsKML.kmz

In QGIS you can label the KMZ by name and style as you want.

Export to GeoPDF (120dpi)

Here is an example: QGIS and the output geopdf with labels

[image]

After comments:

To add a GeoPDF (QGIS 3.20 used) use Raster and select the PDF file.
Example:
[image]

Comment: How do you add a PDF to QGIS? When I try to add it I get a error saying "Invalid Data Source: CopperVeg is not a valid or recognized data source."

Comment: Use Add Raster - added image to the answer.

Comment: As I commented to another Avenza related question, your map will be rasterised on upload to Avenza, so there is no real advantage to using geopdf over geotiff. I've experienced problems with rasterizing pattern fills on upload, so you might want to use geotiff to insure you'll get exactly what you're seeing on your QGIS screen.